# Date Diff in calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a computed column to display the number of days between now and a date in another field. I have tried the following:

```
DATEDIFF(d, @Now(), [NextServiceDate])
```

But I get the following error:

'Assets' table
- Error validating the formula for column 'DaysTillService'.

I have tried without the @ but I get the same error.

Comment: We need to see the whole query. The error you displayed has no connection with your code sample

Comment: This is the whole formula that I have entered into the computed column field. I get the error when I try to save the changes to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try `getdate()`:

```
DaysTileService as (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), NextServiceDate))
```

Comment: Based on your suggestion this worked: (datediff(day,getdate(),[NextServiceDate])). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@Now()` is invalid.  It is a mixture of a variable name (prefix `@`) and a function (`()`).

Try this:

`DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()`

and change your code to:

`DATEDIFF(d, @Now, [NextServiceDate])`

Comment: You cant declare in a computed field can you?

Comment: I think you have a mixture of language statements here.  `Now()` is a VB function.  `@Now` is simply a T-SQL variable

Comment: Yeah. As per Gordon's suggestion below the getdate() function worked. Thanks for your help